# DHCP packets broadcast on all ports on a switch?

Tags: networking, dhcp, switch

I would like to monitor DHCP packets on a clientPC connected
to a 4 port switch/router.

Will i be able to see DHCP packets sent or received on clients
connected to other ports on this switch as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DHCP Discovers and Requests (from client to server):** Yes. These are broadcast, and therefore everyone on the same network segment will receive them.

**DHCP Offers and Acks (from server to client):** Normally no. On a switched network these packets are only forwarded to the client requesting them to begin with, using the switch's ARP table to determine the physical port. Also, I remember using [Ettercap](http://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/) for this exact purpose maybe 10-15 years ago.

-However-

You can sniff for it. The concept goes like this:

1. Spoof the MAC address of your target
2. Receive and read packets
3. Reinsert (forward) the packet once done with it, so that it can reach its correct destination

Many software suites combine the above three steps in various shapes and forms, but a very common one is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which is available for multiple platforms. This also allows you to see the DHCP requests that are normally ignored by your OS. tcpdump is also a very common tool, but as far as I'm aware, that's only available for Linux and Unix-like systems, plus it doesn't do spoofed sniffing.

Basically, what you're after is something that allows for "Unified sniffing via ARP poisoning" in addition to the packet capture ability.

Comment: I ran some tests with tcpdump on my raspbian machine and it seems to work but with the limits you described. Is it possible to see failed IP requests from wificlients with invalid wpa passwords using the sniff method?

Comment: @lincow That would be a regular packet capture. What you need on top of that is to ensure that you still receive packets not intended for you, for example by poisoning the ARP cache of the DHCP server.

Comment: I found there is a console version of wireshark called tshark , i will install this on my pi and play with this tool.

Comment: @lincow tshark works the same as wireshark. You will still need to utilize sniffing to see DHCP offers to other clients, tho.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to see the *broadcast* messages from the server and clients, but some information will be transmitted by *unicast* rather than broadcast, and that depends on the state of the client and how it chooses to follow the RFC 2131 spec.  You *may* be able to see some of the unicast traffic from other ports on your switch, but don't expect to.  Renewals typically use unicast.

http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/2131/33.htm

> When the DHCP client knows the address of a DHCP server, in either INIT or REBOOTING state, the client ***may*** use that address in the DHCPDISCOVER or DHCPREQUEST *rather than the IP broadcast address.*

This table summarizes some of the broadcast / unicast states.
http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/2131/28.htm

Discovery packets are always broadcast.  Request is always broadcast *if the client does not have an address,* but *may* be unicast on renewal.  Offers and acknowledgement packets may be either depending on implementation.  I would recommend reading the RFC to get familiar with when broadcast is used.  You are more likely to see the traffic on initial address acquisition than on renewals.